# JQuery check box doesn't keep checked=''checked'

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am updating my check box programmatically

```
$("span[data-id=test] input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Visually it works perfect.

But

1. When I am looking in page source it does't set checked=''checked', if I do it manually it does.
2. it dissapere after postback,
3. I can't use in in ASP.NET in postback events,

I was trying different ways:

```
.prop('checked', true);
.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

The same issues..

Comment: Try a refresh after you set it to checked. you could use a header meta refresh or a jquery refresh.

Comment: The page source wont show the change as there wasn't a post back but if you use Firefox to inspect element you will see the difference. If you want it to recheck after postback be sure the event is rewired. I cant see that from what you posted

Comment: @James using id is not related to the q.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. Where do you execute that code? In the document ready event? at the end of the body? Any other place? Also keep in mind that "asp.net postback" is just an abstraction (an a poor one) over standard http post method. Every time your page posts back it is actually rendering back from the start, and with viewstate you have the illusion state is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

`'checked=checked'` will not ( and does not suppose to) be on the view source. (*when modifying dom via js*)

You changed the DOM tree attributes. you **didn't** change the html markup !

These  kind of changes are visible to  Firebug or better , chrome developer toolbar

For the "disappear after postback" , it does not. it can't be. it is an input which its value is transferred to the server. You must have something else there.

Comment: More info:     Iam updating check box on other check box changed. I ned to automatically checked some of check box when one of them checked by the user.  And I am using Firebug and can see checked = 'checked' for checked box updated by a user manually. But pro grammatically updated stay the same - there is no checked attribut however it looks like checked in the browser

Comment: I'm having a similar problem where my checkbox is checked visibly after a postback, but the jQuery I'm running at DOM loaded says .is(':checked') is false.